# Django migration error : return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.ProgrammingError:

Tags: django, sqlite, migration, makemigrations

I tried to delete the migrations folder and db.sqlite3 as suggestions but it didn't work. I've also tried to downgrade version of django.  Please look at the error below, I think it's the problem with database :

```
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
        main()
      File "manage.py", line 17, in main
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\store2\env2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\store2\env2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
        django.setup()
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\store2\env2\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\store2\env2\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
        app_config.import_models()
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\store2\env2\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
        self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
      File "c:\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\store2\Django-E-Commerce-master\user\models.py", line 8, in <module>
        from home.models import Language
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\store2\Django-E-Commerce-master\home\models.py", line 21, in <module>
        for rs in llist:
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\store2\env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 268, in __iter__
        self._fetch_all()
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\store2\env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186, in _fetch_all
        self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\store2\env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 54, in __iter__
        results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\store2\env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1065, in execute_sql
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\store2\env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
        return super().execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\store2\env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
        return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\store2\env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
        return executor(sql, params, many, context)
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\store2\env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\store2\env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
        raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
      File "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\store2\env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "home_language" does not exist
    LINE 1: ...ge"."create_at", "home_language"."update_at" FROM "home_lang...
```

This is setting file,

```
import os
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '!l3!x0w-(f39+(@*a3a^8p@gf+o66e(@c#w1u13u*0=#-qpxbn'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'user.apps.UserConfig',
    'order.apps.OrderConfig',
    'product.apps.ProductConfig',
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ckeditor',
    'mptt',
    'currencies',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'currencies.context_processors.currencies'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('tr', _('Turkish')),
]

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
DEFAULT_CURRENCY = 'USD'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')

# ...
SITE_ID = 1

####################################
##  CKEDITOR CONFIGURATION ##
####################################

CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'images/'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': None,
    },
}

###################################

#APPEND_SLASH=False
```

This is the model part where it is printing out the error :

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    code= models.CharField(max_length=5)
    status=models.BooleanField()
    create_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

llist = Language.objects.filter(status=True)
list1 = []
for rs in llist:
    list1.append((rs.code,rs.name))
langlist = (list1)
```

I think there's something wrong with this part of model.py since it throws out same error when I delete everything and leave only this part in models.py

I think the cause is this line `llist = Language.objects.filter(status=True)`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  In order to help you, you need to provide the relevant code.

Comment: As @ewong suggested,  improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear, Have a look here => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Other user won't be able to help you if you don't add some code

Comment: Given what you have posted... have you ran `manage.py makemigrations` to create your migrations and `manage.py migrate` to migrate your database? Because all we can see, is that your database doesn't contain what your code thinks it does.

Comment: @knight, are you able to fix this error if yes, kindly drop your solution.